# Part of model not rendered

Tags: rendering

[image]

I have made a model of hat. it has 3 parts buckle round strip and hat. hat and strip is not rendered.only buckle is rendering.. I made sure camera icon and checked. plz see to it.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=evq7rp6d" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/evq7rp6d/)

Comment: I dont know... but its rendering... i also did what wiseman answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked the Cylinder object hierarchy? Make sure all the objects in that hierarchy are selected and have the camera Icon checked in the Outliner Section.

Comment: i think the hierarchy is ok... i have attached the blend file too.. plz have a look at it..

Comment: I looked at the file and there were some modifiers which were off for the viewport which is not thing to worry about. But the scene rendered just fine(As you are rendering in the Evee, I would suggest you to improve it by enabling AO option, use an HDRI and color management->look->medium high contrast). All the things rendering were just fine(I rendered few frames to check it), no problem at all.

Comment: u mean everything is fine and nothing needs to change? its fine?

Comment: yes Thanks.. i change it to OA... color management... and sub division unchecked for GPU.... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling GPU subdivision to see if it helps:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked...

Comment: @user152225 This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).